# Is it advised to do treatment-covariate interactions to estimate the average treatment effect when using exact matching?

Tags: r, matching

I am using `method = “exact”` from the `MatchIt` package. In the vignette of `MatchIt`, it is advised to run treatment-covariate interactions to account for treatment heterogeneity across covariates. I have two questions in this regard:

1. I assume this is also advised for exact matching and not only when balance is not perfectly achieved?
2. In my case, I use matching in the context of making immigrants coming from two country groups more comparable to each other using cross-national and cross-sectional data. To ensure that control units are interviewed in the same host country and time as treatment units, I match, besides a couple of covariates, also on host country and year. When using treatment-covariate interactions to account for effect heterogeneity, should these interactions exclude the country and time given that they are technically not pre-treatment, which would be in this case anything pre-migration?

```r
library(MatchIt)

  matobj_list <- matchit(treatment ~ a + b + c + d + hostcountry + 
                     year, data = df_mat,  method = "exact")

  matched.dat <- match.data(matobj_list, data = df_mat)

  ## Estimation after matching
  # all covariate-interactions

  lm(y ~ treatment * (a + b + c + d + hostcountry + year), 
         data = matched.dat, weights = weights)

  ## or

  lm(y ~ treatment * (a + b + c + d) + hostcountry + year, 
         data = matched.dat, weights = weights)
```

Comment: No matter what model you use, the estimates will be the same. Try it and see.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, estimates are the same, but standard errors and as a result confidence intervals are a bit different.

Comment: You appear to be using an ordinary linear model that does not take matching into account formally in the analysis.  This is a problem.  Also, doesn’t matching make estimation of interaction effects more challenging?  What made you think of matching in this study as opposed to simple modeling that does not have to sacrifice any of the observations?